# How to remove the swipe-delete button in one table & not another in a same view screen in Obj C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In a iPhone application, I am using two different tableviews in same screen. Now, I want to use the swipe-delete functionality in one table view but not in the other. But when I call the delegate method 'commiteditingstyledelete' to get the swipe-delete button in both the table view. How to remove that from the other table ? I can not disable the row user-interaction as I have some textfield in tableview row. Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your delegate callback for editing cells, you have to check what table you want to use, you can set a tag to each tableView, or you're using ivars check for the instance, so:

1: with ivars

```
if(tableView==yourTableViewClassVar){
  //your table
}
```

2: with tag

```
set the tag 
tableView.tag=10;
```

...then in the callback

```
if(tableView.tag==10){
   //your table
}
```

EDIT:

> The problem is , even when I swipe across Table2, the
>   commiteditingstyle method is called and shows the delete button.

you also have to check set style of the cell in this callback:

```
  - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (tableView.tag==10) {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
        }else{
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I am using tags to distinguish two table views. My code is like this:

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       if(tableview.tag==TABLE1_TAG){
             //Do the delete action
        }
}`

The problem is , even when I swipe across Table2, the commiteditingstyle method is called and shows the delete button. As I did not put any action on this Table2 delete button thanks to tags),it does not do any action.But the point is, it should not appear on swiping.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..... your edit helped greatly .. It actually SOLVED my issue .. Cheers :)

Comment: You're welcome..remember to mark the answer as accepted if you think that it has solved your problem, upvote if it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate method is called with a tableView parameter. Compare this parameter to your hopefully as member variables stored tableViews. So you can choose for which tableView to activate and for which not.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a different delegate object for the UITableView.